# How to monitor solr indexing speed?

Tags: solr

I'm working with solr to index a large amount of documents. And I would like to monitor the indexing speed of these documents.

I generate my documents collection into CSV files and then I index my documents via CURL. 
So i can get the QTime in ms. I can then check the indexing speed by CSV file doing this simple calculation :

indexing speed = number of documents in my CSV File / Qtime

```
From Solr Documentation : 
QTime: The elapsed time (in milliseconds) between the arrival of the request (when the SolrQueryRequest object is created) and the completion of the request handler. It does not include time spent in the response writer formatting/streaming the response to the client.
```

I'm not sure that is the right way to monitor indexing speed. It's not very precise, and the result doesn't seem very good...

Are there some tools that I can use instead of this archaic method ?! :)

Thank

Comment: Nope. you have the check the logs and generate stats for this.

Comment: Where can I check the logs and stats ?

Comment: Solr logs can be checked with the tomcat logs itself if set to debug or INFO it should print indexing time for each request.

Answer (score 1):

You can use solrmeter https://code.google.com/p/solrmeter/ to monitor indexing speed